# Cannot setup python properly with pyenv

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I got a new Mac and I was trying to setup python as I didi in my previous systems.

I followed [this guide](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#installing-pyenv) (and double checked many others like that) but I was not successful at having `python` pointing to the right version.

```
➜  ~ pyenv versions
  system
* 3.9.7 (set by /Users/luca/.pyenv/version)
➜  ~ python -V
Python 2.7.16
➜  ~ which python
/usr/bin/python
➜  ~ pyenv which python
/Users/luca/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/bin/python
```

I did add these lines in `.zshrc`

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
  eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
fi
```

but it keeps giving me the system python 2.7

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution meanwhile.
using the oh-my-zsh plugin for pyenv fixed it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you explain it in details?